# What is the the best coffee-water ratio?

Tags: coffee, french-press

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the Ideal Coffee to Water Ratio for a French Press?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/11162/whats-the-ideal-coffee-to-water-ratio-for-a-french-press)

In terms of weight, what is a recommended relation between coffee and the water, when I'm making coffee in a French-press?

I think this also depends on the size of the grind, but let's suppose a standard one.

Which do you use and what's the strength? Thanks!

Comment: It is a duplicate indeed. I've searched before asking but I couldn't find that question. A merge would be appreciated.