# French Press Coffee amount

Tags: coffee, water, french-press

Okay so I have a french press, and I have been trying to figure out how much coffee I need. Here is the scenario:

It is a 15 oz press, I been reading that the general rule of thumb is 2 tbs of coffee per 6 oz of water, so if my math is correct that would me 5 tbs of coffee. or roughly 25 grams...

This seems like a lot of coffee for that amount of water?

Secondly, do I measure the scoops prior to grinding or after grinding?

I know there isn't an exact answer and there are other variables to consider, but I was wondering if there are any general guide lines I should be following... or opinions about this?

There will be a test later (a taste test) so you better get it right.

Comment: This has already been very well-covered in [What's the Ideal Coffee to Water Ratio for a French Press?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/11162/whats-the-ideal-coffee-to-water-ratio-for-a-french-press). (That question doesn't explicitly ask when to measure, but the answers make it clear it's after grinding). The rest of your question, asking for general guidelines and opinions, isn't really a specific enough question to work well here, but if you have specific follow-up questions please do post them!